# I would like to use data from a table to create a selectmultiple list on my form

Tags: django

I am pretty new to python/django, but previously programmed in C# and VB.Net. I need to create a list on my django form that contains data elements from a PGSQL table. The user should be able to select multiple rows and then I would formulate a query that I would send back to the server. I have researched, but have not found anything to point me in the right direction. I will show my code below.

forms.py

```
PROD_MULTI_RECORDS=[
    ('darryl.dillman','darryl.dillman'),
    ('richard.mcgarry','richard.mcgarry'),
    ('janet.delage','janet.delage')
    ]

class rdsprodform(forms.Form):

selectmulti = 
forms.CharField(widget=forms.SelectMultiple(choices=PROD_MULTI_RECORDS), 
required = False, label = "Please select records to process")
```

Comment: I think you should learn about Django Forms and Inline Formsets.

Comment: Thanks for your non help. I am going through some training for django forms now, but I am also actively working on a project where I need some help. I stupidly thought this was that kind of site, but I guess I was wrong. I will look elsewhere for an answer.

Comment: Welcome to the Stack Overflow. You are precisely right that this is not a kind of website where you post your objective and people would provide full fledged working codes for you. Instead, here you post your full fledged attempt to attain your objective and people help you to sort out things going wrong in it.